# GitHub Releases y GitHub Packages

Tags: github, packages

### Exposición del problema

He escrito una librería JavaScript que deseo hacer accesible en proyectos de terceros (al igual que jQuery), para ello he pensado en valerme del servicio [JSDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/) y su opción GitHub.

Primero hice un Package npm a través de GitHub (pensando que era necesario) pero luego noté que no funcionaba y solo después de hacer un Release en GitHub fue posible importar la librería usando: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/user/repo@version/file`

También tuve que realizar una nueva versión del programa por medio de Release pero a la hora de hacer lo mismo en Packages no encontré la manera, así que tengo una versión Release `v1.0.1` y un Packages `v1.0.0` y desconozco la forma de alinear la versión de Packages.

### Conclusión

- ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre Packages y Releases, ambos son necesarios para el servicio JSDelivr?
- ¿Cómo se crea una nueva versión de un GitHub Package (ej: v.1.0.1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre Packages y Releases, ambos son necesarios para el servicio jsdelivr?**

Una *release* indica una versión del código que contiene el repositorio

[image: GitHub Releases y GitHub Packages]

Cuando se crea una *release*, se guarda el código que se tiene en el repositorio y se sube como *release*, posteriormente se puede descargar y los archivos ya se pueden borrar, pues ya se publicaron como *release*

En cambio, los paquetes (*packages*) son integraciones de servicios externos con el repositorio, como lo dice en [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/about-github-packages):

> GitHub Packages es un servicio de alojamiento de paquetes de software que le permite alojar sus paquetes de software de forma privada o pública y utilizarlos como dependencias en sus proyectos. <sub>Fuente: [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/about-github-packages)</sub>

**Es decir**, que si se necesita, se pueden usar paquetes que se hayan publicado en repositorios como dependencias en otros paquetes, mientras que las releases solo son versiones del repositorio

**Ambos no son necesarios**, solo tienes que hacer un *release*, ya que *JSDelivr* cuenta con servicio de CDN para GitHub de la siguiente manera

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/user/repo@version/file
```

En este caso, vamos a solicitar un archivo de *jQuery*

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jquery/jquery@3.5.0/src/jquery.js
```

Si compruebas, lo carga correctamente y jQuery no cuenta con ningún paquete

[image: GitHub Releases y GitHub Packages]

---

**2. ¿Cómo se crea una nueva versión de un GitHub Package (ej: v.1.0.1)?**

[Fuente: GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/guides/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-packages)

De forma predeterminada, los paquetes de GitHub publican un paquete en el repositorio de GitHub que especifique en el campo de nombre del archivo `package.json`. Por ejemplo, publicaría un paquete llamado `@my-org/test` en el repositorio de GitHub `my-org/test`. Puede agregar un resumen para la página de listado de paquetes incluyendo un archivo README.md en su directorio de paquetes. Para obtener más información, consulte [*Trabajar con package.json*](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file) y _[Cómo crear módulos *Node.js* en la documentación de *npm*](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules).

Puede configurar el mapeo de alcance para su proyecto usando un archivo `.npmrc` local en el proyecto o usando la opción *publishConfig* en el `package.json`. Los paquetes de GitHub solo admiten paquetes *npm* con ámbito. Los paquetes con ámbito tienen nombres con el formato `@propietario/nombre`. Los paquetes con ámbito siempre comienzan con un símbolo @. Es posible que deba actualizar el nombre en su package.json para usar el nombre de ámbito. Por ejemplo, "nombre": "@codertocat/hello-world-npm".

Después de publicar un paquete, puede verlo en GitHub. Para obtener más información, consulte [*Visualización de paquetes*](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/manage-packages/viewing-packages).

Sin embargo, no se pueden publicar versiones específicas de un paquete, puedes **publicar una release**, de la siguiente manera:

- Entra al repositorio en el que quieres publicar la versión
- Ubica la sección de *releases*

[image: GitHub Releases y GitHub Packages]

- Presiona *Releases*
- Ubica el botón *Draft a new release* y presiónalo

[image: GitHub Releases y GitHub Packages]

- Rellena los campos correspondientes:

El input *tag version* es el número de versión, por ejemplo, si es 1.4, en JSDelivr será accesible así:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/user/repo@1.4/file
```

El input *release title* es lo que se muestra de título, es decir

[image: GitHub Releases y GitHub Packages]

(La descripción de la release es opcional)

Finalmente, presiona el botón *Publish release* ¡Y listo!